# How to prevent selection in datatable for users only (by click)?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datagrid, selection, webix

use-case: datatable selection (Webix datatable) needs to be set programmatically, but users shouldn't have a possibility to change it by clicking the rows.
I've tried

```
onItemClick:function(){
    return false
}
```

It does nothing. I've also tried

```
on:{
  onBeforeSelect:function(){
    return false
  }
},
```

[snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/4579b865)

It prevents the selection globally, inluding the `select()` method. Is there a way to prevent the selection by click only?
Visible selection by CSS doesn't suit, as I need to get the selected value afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use code like next

```
$$("grid").on_click.webix_cell = function(){}
$$("grid").select(1);
```

http://webix.com/snippet/2a428a8b

First line in above snippet blocks all click-based operations for the target component.